# Understanding the Purpose of Copying Resources to the Asset Directory in Android Projects

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm working on an Android project and have noticed that all resources (like images) added to the project are also copied to the asset directory. This seems a bit redundant to me because these resources appear to be included in the binary and are loaded directly from there. So, I'm trying to understand the specific purpose or advantage of this approach.

Could someone explain why Delphi copy project resources to the asset directory in Android, especially when they are already included in the binary?

Any insights or explanations regarding these practices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Why is it a common practice to copy project resources to the asset directory in Android, especially when they are already included in the binary?` That is no common practice. I never did that. Please give example(s).

Comment: You forgot to tell where an added image resource landed first.

Comment: How did you check that it works even without StartUpCopy? Did you delete any existing resources in the Asset directory before?

Comment: @blackapps by common practice I mean that delphi do it every time for us (I updated the question, thanks). just make a new multi platform project, then project >resources and images > add a new image. then compile and deploy. the resource image is duplicated in the binary and also in the asset folder (+also duplicated somewhere else than the asset folder via the System.StartUpCopy)

Comment: @UweRaabe exactly, I removed the System.StartUpCopy, deleted the app from my android and then redeploy and everything still work fine. If you look the code of TResourceStream you will see that it's load the resource only from the binary not from any directory.

Comment: You have already asked that question before. If you want to bring attention to the question post the bounty instead of asking the question again.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar the question I asked before was regarding the purpose of System.StartUpCopy as at this time resources was not stored inside the binary and now it's the case. question is different, here it's to ask why ressource are duplicated inside the asset directory when they are read only from inside the binary

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I removed all reference to StartUpCopy to make the question unique. could you please remove now the duplicate flag ?

Comment: Well, if you are asking about something besides `StartUpCopy`, you would have to provide more details. I don't see any such duplication of files. If you are still asking about those files that are copied by `StartUpCopy` then removing the reference to it, just makes your question less clear and it is still a duplicate.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar not at all regarding StartUpCopy. startupCopy simply copy the file from the asset directory to another directory making 2x more space necessary (I do not know why but that another question that I made in the post you link). Here i ask why Delphi duplicate the resource inside the binary AND in the asset folder.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate resources inside the binary and in the asset folder. Please edit the question and provide [mcve] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar how it's possible you do not see any duplicates ? compile for android, look the size of the .so, add a resource of say 10 MB, important save now the project. Compile again for android then deploy also. go in the android folder, look the asset folder with the 10 mb resource and also look the size of the .so that grow by 10 mb.

Comment: If you add resource in the asset folder, then of course, that this asset will be included in the binary. How else would you deploy the asset to the users? But there is no duplication, besides what the `StartUpCopy` is doing.  I have analyzed release APKs and AABs built with Delphi 12 in Android Studio and whatever I add, it is only included once. If you see something else then please edit the question and add the steps to reproduce the issue. If you are asking about `StartUpCopy` then the question is duplicate.